# Vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}[x]_n$ result

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I was revising my linear algebra, and the solution to some questions took a step I didn't understand. In both, they mentioned "from calculus", but I don't know where from. The first example:

Let $U$ be the vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}[x]_n$ where:
$$U:=\{p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]_n : p(1)=0\}$$
Then by calculus we know that:
$$U=\{(x-1)q(x) : q(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]_{n-1}\}$$

Then a second one says something similar:
$$U:=\{p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]_n : p(0)=p(1)=0,p'(0)=0\}$$
Then:
$$U=\{x^2(x-1)q(x) : q(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]_{n-3}\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement it's an application of the [Factor Theorem](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Polynomial_Factor_Theorem).

The  second, follows from the Factor Theorem and the fact that $p(0)=p'(0)=0$ implies that $0$ it's a repeated root (repeated at least two times) of $p$. Both are Theorems about polynomials which I'd say is basic algebra instead of calculus.